# Implementing 2 select boxes from php array

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am having a php array like this..

```
$food = array ("Fruits" => array("apple","mango","orange"), "vegies"=> array ("capsicum", "betroot", "raddish"), "bisucuits"=>array("marygold", "britania", "goodday"));
```

i have to define two select boxes. 1st select box I have to choose a category. In the 2nd select box I need to get values of subcategory. How can I implement?

Comment: [tag:Java] related?

Comment: no html related

Comment: Deepak -- then why did you give the question a [tag:java] question tag? You don't want to use wrong tags as that can attract *negative* attention to your question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Probably confused java and javascript unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this on my phone. Apologies for mistakes.

```
$food = array ("Fruits" => array("apple","mango","orange"), "vegies"=> array ("capsicum", "betroot", "raddish"), "bisucuits"=>array("marygold", "britania", "goodday"));

echo "<select name='myFood'>";
foreach ($food as $cat)
{
    echo "<optgroup label='$cat'>";
    foreach ($cat as $foodVal)
    {
         echo "<option value='$foodVal'>$foodVal</option>";
    }
    echo "</optgroup>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Effectively, using the two sets of for each will allow you to go through the multidimensional array properly.

`optgroup` will create headings inside the select

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it is to print out a main `select` with veggies, biscuits and fruits.  Next, you should print out the their sublists as selects.  Then, you can use jQuery to maintain which should be visible:

```
<?php

$food = array ("Fruits" => array("apple","mango","orange"), "vegies"=> array ("capsicum", "betroot", "raddish"), "bisucuits"=>array("marygold", "britania", "goodday"));


echo "<select id='main'>";
foreach ($food as $key => $value) {
    echo "<option value='$key'>$key</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

foreach ($food as $key => $value) {
    echo "<select class='sublist' id='$key'>";
    foreach ($value as $item) {
        echo "<option value='$item'>$item</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
}

?>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$("#main").change(function () {
    $(".sublist").hide();
    $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
});
$("#main").trigger("change");
</script>
```

Live version:

http://neil.computer/stack/ex1.php

Comment: @deepakasai You're welcome. If you could mark as solution, it'd help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Using only **PHP**

```
$food = array ("Fruits" => array("apple","mango","orange"), "vegies"=> array ("capsicum", "betroot", "raddish"), "bisucuits"=>array("marygold", "britania", "goodday"));
$out = "";
foreach($food as $k => $v) {
    $out .= '<select name="'.$k.'">';
    foreach($v as $value) {
        $out .= '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
    }
    $out .= '</select>';
}
echo $out;
// output
<select name="Fruits">
<option value="apple">apple</option>
<option value="mango">mango</option>
<option value="orange">orange</option>
</select>
<select name="vegies">
<option value="capsicum">capsicum</option>
<option value="betroot">betroot</option>
<option value="raddish">raddish</option>
</select>
<select name="bisucuits">
<option value="marygold">marygold</option>
<option value="britania">britania</option>
<option value="goodday">goodday</option>
</select>
```

Check it on [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1731fc9edf035e089b702526812677b2d81d9395)

**Edit** - Same result using `array_walk`

```
array_walk($food, function($v,$k) {
    echo '<select name="'.$k.'">';
    array_walk($v, function($value,$key) {
        echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
    });
   echo '</select>'; 
});
```